# zend soap win7/apache cant remove cache

Tags: zend-framework, zend-soap

I did everything, i think:

deleted `windows/Temp`
`soap.wsdl_cache_enabled=0` in **php.ini** and restarted apache
`ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");` in handleWDSL, handleSOAP and clientAction!

what else? still getting:
Message: Function ("arrays_work") is not a valid method for this service

That is the new function I added to the service. Also, if I change oldones, nothing happens (for instance, adding functionality to access db).

please...
any clues?

Answer (score 0):

This was solved and in this case was related to other thing: the uri for the wdsl was pointing to an oldone... sorry..